# How do developers receive git pull requests?

Tags: git

There are lots of tutorials about git pull requests (e.g. [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/) and [here](https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/)) but they explain how to generate a pull request, not how they are received. If the upstream developer and I are using git at the terminal and I generate a pull request, say using [git request-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull):

```
git request-pull master https://git.blah.org/project
```

How does the upstream development team know that they have an incoming pull request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git itself has no auto-communicating concept of pull-requests. If you Use GitHub or GitLab or any other Git hosting platform that supports pull requests, you open the pull request in the Web interface or via some additional command-line tool like `git-spindle`. Then the upstream user gets notified according to the hosting platform like receiving and e-mail or getting it displayed in the web interface.

Using `git request-pull` command just creates some text that you can e-mail or instant message or whatever to the upstream user that tells him "please pull from my repository" which of course only works if the user has direct access to your local repository to pull from.

You can also use `git format-patch` to generate a patch-set for your intended changes and mail those patches to the upstream user that then can use `git am` to apply your changes.

How an upstream project expects contributions depends on the upstream project and you have to ask them how they want to receive contributions.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull):

> Generate a request asking your upstream project to pull changes into their tree. **The request, printed to the standard output**, begins with the branch description, summarizes the changes and indicates from where they can be pulled.

You copy and paste the request into an e-mail and send it to the upstream development team.

Answer (score 0):

in this level of git using you must have a mecanisme to send a notifications and visualisation so you need to use a git provider gitlab , github for a ui, because git can't manage this topic